# Clone of mobile game Ballz

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a clone of the mobile game [Ballz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballz_(mobile_game)), and it works quite well. However, there are a few problems:

- Performance. When I have more than 50 balls in the game, the FPS dips from 60. I am unsure how to (A) improve the performance of the game and (B) adapt to a low frame rate such that the game physics continues to work properly and the user sees the objects moving at the same speed.
- Collisions: Most of the time, collisions work fine. However, when I up the speed of the balls they can sometimes go through boxes. This is not the desired result, but I am again unsure of how to fix it.
- I am new to programming with Python, though I am fairly experienced in other languages. I would like to know if there are any small things I can improve with my style. Specifically, to create the singleton class `board` I have simply created it as a class with only static methods and variables. Is there a better way to define a singleton?
- I would like to know how I have done with my OOP, i.e. do any objects "know" about each other that shouldn't?
- Lastly, if there are any glitches or obvious errors I've missed please point them out!

---

My code is divided into several different class. Here is an image showing the flow of my program:

[image: Pickle rick]
Here is a brief summary of each class (Note that I use `import pygame as pyg`):

- the measures module contains variables that I want to have standardized throughout the code. This includes things like the width and height of the window and borders.
- The `ball` class is derived from `pyg.sprite.Sprite`. It is first `launch()`ed when the user hits the mouse button, and, if it falls to the ground first, sets a new "center" from which the balls are launched in the next round (`ball.terminus.x`)
- The `item` class, derived from `pyg.sprite.Sprite` contains all of the functions used by both `ball_adder` and `box`, such as moving according to the `step` given, and has overridable functions `draw()` and `handleCollision()`
- The `ball_adder` class, derived from `item`, disappears when hit by a ball and drops a new ball at the base (ball addition is handled by `board`)
- The `box` class, derived from `item`, has a `number` representing its "strength". Every time it is hit by a ball, `number` is decreased. After hitting 0, the `box` instance disappears.
- The `board` class contains a `pyg.sprite.Group` of balls(`board.balls`) and has a list of groups for each row of the board (`board_row`) which contains every `box` and `ball_adder`, and each row of balls (`ball_row`, used to optimize collisions)

---

Here is my code (I apologize if it takes a long time to read through it all):
**measures.py**

```
window = (375, 585)
radius = 7
dimension = 45
step = 5 #space between each item in the grid

#border width (for the left and side borders) and height (for the top and bottom borders)
side_width = 10
top_height = 65

#grid positions for the boxes and ball_adders 
xs = [side_width + step + (dimension + step)*x for x in range(0,7)]
ys = [top_height + dimension + 2*step + (dimension + step) * x for x in range(0,8)]
```

---

**item.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
import measures

class item(pyg.sprite.Sprite):
    """Base class for the members of board_row"""
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos = -1):
        pyg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #Check if the item is a new instance or loaded from the json file. If new, place it at the initial y value.
        y = 0
        if y_pos == -1:
            y = measures.top_height + measures.step
        else:
            y = measures.ys[y_pos]

        self.rect = pyg.Rect(measures.xs[x_pos], y, measures.dimension, measures.dimension)
        self.stepper = 0.00

        self.moving = True #always move the item when it is created

    def draw(self):
        """Handled by the child classes"""
        pass

    def initiateMove(self):
        """Start moving the item"""
        self.moving = True
        self.stepper = 0

    def updatePosition(self, step):
        if self.moving:
            #Move object
            self.stepper += step
            if self.stepper >= step: #Once a full step has ocurred, move the object internally. This ugly workaround is necessary because pyg.Rect.top is an int
               self.stepper -= 1
               self.rect.top += 1

            #Check if the item has hit the next y_pos
            try:
                measures.ys.index(self.rect.top)
                self.moving = False
            except:
                pass


    def update(self, step):
        """Updates the position and draws the item"""
        self.updatePosition(step)
        self.draw()

    def handle_collision():
        """Handled by the child classes"""
        pass
```

---

**Box.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
import random
from item import item
import measures
pyg.font.init() #Throws an error when declaring box.box_font if it is not called

class box(item):
    box_font = pyg.font.Font("Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf", 20)

    def __init__(self, game_level, x_pos, y_pos=-1, number = 0):
        item.__init__(self, x_pos, y_pos)

        #Check if this is a new box instance or loaded from a json file. If new, assign it with a 3/4 of being game_level, 
        #and a 1/4 chance of being 2*game_level 
        if number == 0:
            self.number = random.randint(1, 4)
            if self.number == 1:
                self.number = 2*game_level 
            else:
                self.number = game_level
        else:
            self.number = number

        self.number_text = box.box_font.render(str(self.number), True, (0,0,0))

        #Pick the color
        self.color = pyg.Color(0,0,0)
        if self.number <= 5:
            self.color = pyg.Color(245, 181, 46)
        elif 5 < self.number <= 12:
            self.color = pyg.Color(129, 197, 64)
        elif 12 < self.number <= 31:
            self.color = pyg.Color(234, 34, 94)
        elif 31 < self.number < 50:
            self.color = pyg.Color(196, 34, 132)
        elif 50 <= self.number:
            self.color = pyg.Color(22, 116, 188)

    def handle_collision(self):
        """decrements the number and updates the text to match it. If number <= 0, kill()"""
        self.number -= 1
        self.number_text = box.box_font.render(str(self.number), True, (0,0,0))
        self.color.r = min(self.color.r + 10, 255)

        if self.number <= 0:
            self.kill()

    def draw(self):
        """Draws the rect and the text centered on the rect"""
        number_text_rect = self.number_text.get_rect()
        number_text_rect.center = self.rect.center

        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()

        pyg.draw.rect(display_surface, self.color, self.rect)
        display_surface.blit(self.number_text, number_text_rect)
```

---

**Ball_Adder.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
from pygame import gfxdraw
from item import item
import measures

class ball_adder(item):
    outer_width = 2
    outer_radius = measures.radius + 8

    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos = -1):
        item.__init__(self, x_pos, y_pos)

    def draw(self):
        """Draws the inner circle and the outer ring"""
        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()
        rect_center = self.rect.center

        gfxdraw.aacircle(display_surface, rect_center[0], rect_center[1], ball_adder.outer_radius, (255,255,255))

        #create the outline width since pygame doesn't implement it that.
        for i in range(1, ball_adder.outer_width):
           gfxdraw.circle(display_surface, rect_center[0], rect_center[1], ball_adder.outer_radius - i, (255,255,255))

        gfxdraw.aacircle(display_surface, rect_center[0], rect_center[1], ball_adder.outer_radius - ball_adder.outer_width, (255,255,255))

        gfxdraw.aacircle(display_surface, rect_center[0], rect_center[1], measures.radius, (255,255,255))
        gfxdraw.filled_circle(display_surface, rect_center[0], rect_center[1], measures.radius, (255, 255, 255))

    def handle_collision(self):
        """If there is a collision, disappear"""
        self.kill()
```

---

**ball.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
from pygame import gfxdraw
import math
import measures

class ball(pyg.sprite.Sprite):
    radius = 7
    terminus = pyg.math.Vector2(measures.window[0] // 2, measures.window[1] - measures.top_height - measures.radius - 1) #launching point
    new_terminus_x = 0
    first = False #Flag that determines whether or not to update new_terminus_x upon hitting the ground
    speed = 10 

    def __init__(self, x=0):
        pyg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.vector = pyg.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.moving = False 
        self.launching = False #Flag that says whether or not the ball is launching (updated in board and the launch thread)

        #Set new_terminus_x when starting up the class (avoids the ball flying off the screen when no board.json exists)
        if ball.new_terminus_x == 0:
            ball.new_terminus_x = ball.terminus.x

        #If it is 0, it is "dropped" from a ball_adder onto the correct x value, instead of at terminus.x
        if x == 0:
            x = ball.terminus.x

        self.center = pyg.math.Vector2(x, ball.terminus.y)

    def draw(self):
        """Draw"""
        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()

        gfxdraw.aacircle(display_surface, int(self.center.x), int(self.center.y), measures.radius, (255,255,255))
        gfxdraw.filled_circle(display_surface, int(self.center.x), int(self.center.y), measures.radius, (255,255,255))


    def launch(self):
        self.moving = True
        self.launching = False #Not launching if you have already launched

    def update(self, step):
        from Board import board

        self.draw()
        if self.moving:
            #Move along the vector
            self.center -= step*ball.speed*self.vector

            #Detects collision with the border
            #right side
            if self.center.x + 7 >= board.borders[3].left:
                self.center.x = board.borders[3].left - measures.radius
                self.vector.x *= -1
            #left side
            elif self.center.x - 7 <= board.borders[2].left:
                self.center.x = board.borders[2].left + board.borders[2].width + measures.radius
                self.vector.x *= -1
            #top
            elif self.center.y - 7 <= board.borders[0].top + board.borders[0].height:
                self.center.y = board.borders[0].top + board.borders[0].height + measures.radius
                self.vector.y *= -1
            #bottom
            elif self.center.y + 7 >= board.borders[1].top:
                self.moving = False
                #If the first variable is false, then that means no other ball has set it to be true. Set it true and update new_terminus_x
                if not ball.first:
                    ball.first = True
                    ball.new_terminus_x = self.center.x
        elif not self.launching:
            #Once the ball hits the ground, slide it over to new_terminus_x
            if abs(self.center.x - ball.new_terminus_x) < ball.speed/2:
                self.center = pyg.math.Vector2(ball.new_terminus_x, ball.terminus.y)
            if self.center.x < ball.new_terminus_x:
                self.center = pyg.math.Vector2(self.center.x + ball.speed, ball.terminus.y)
            elif self.center.x > ball.new_terminus_x:
                self.center = pyg.math.Vector2(self.center.x - ball.speed, ball.terminus.y) 

            #update the direction vector according to the angle between mouse and terminus
            angle = 0
            mouse_pos = pyg.mouse.get_pos()
            if mouse_pos[1] < self.center.y - measures.radius: 
                try:
                    angle = math.atan((mouse_pos[1] - self.center.y)/(mouse_pos[0] - self.center.x))          
                except:
                    angle = math.pi /2
            else:
                angle = 3*math.pi / 180
                if pyg.mouse.get_pos()[0] > ball.terminus.x:
                    angle *= -1

            if pyg.mouse.get_pos()[0] > ball.terminus.x:
               angle += math.pi


            self.change_vector(angle)

    def change_vector(self, angle):
        """Takes input angle and updates the direction vector"""
        self.vector = pyg.math.Vector2(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))

    def prepare_launch():
        """Resets the speed and first value (used as a flag to determine whether to change new_terminus_x)"""
        ball.first = False
        ball.terminus.x = ball.new_terminus_x
        ball.speed = 10
```

---

**Board.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
from pygame import gfxdraw
import random
import Box
import Ball_Adder
import ball
import button
import math
import os
import json
import measures
pyg.font.init()

def pointOfIntersect(r_center, r_size, c_center):
        """Determines the closest point of a rectangle to a circle"""
        v2_c_center = pyg.math.Vector2(c_center)
        v2_r_center = pyg.math.Vector2(r_center)

        offset = v2_c_center - v2_r_center
        if offset.x == 0 and offset.y == 0:
            return [v2_c_center, v2_r_center]

        if offset.x == 0:   
            ratio = r_size[1] / abs(offset.y)
        elif offset.y == 0: 
            ratio = r_size[0] / abs(offset.x)
        else:
            ratio  = min(r_size[0] / abs(offset.x), r_size[1] / abs(offset.y))
        ratio *= 0.5

        return v2_r_center + (offset * ratio)

class board:
    balls = pyg.sprite.Group() 
    ball_row  = [pyg.sprite.Group() for x in range(0, 7)]
    board_row = [pyg.sprite.Group() for x in range(0, 8)] #The last row is for when they hit they bottom and the entire board is cleared.

    array_moving = False #Flag that is used to make sure that the balls aren't launched while the board is moving

    #game_level and its associated text
    game_level = 1
    game_level_font = pyg.font.Font("Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", 30)
    game_level_rect = pyg.Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
    game_level_text = None

    #Not the actual ball_count, just what is displayed before and while you are launching the balls (goes down each time one is launched)
    ball_count = 1
    gbc_font = pyg.font.Font("Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", 15)
    gbc_rect = pyg.Rect(0,0,0,0)
    gbc_text = None

    #angle between mouse and ball.terminus and the associated text (uses game_level_font)
    mouse_angle = 0
    ma_rect = pyg.Rect(0,0,0,0)
    ma_text = None

    #button that, when pressed, speeds up the balls
    speed_button = button.button_image(0, 0, "Images/Lightning.png", "Images/LightningPressed.png", pyg.Color(255,255,255))

    #window borders and color
    border_color = (56, 56, 56)
    #order: top, bottom, left, right
    borders  = []

    def init():
        #set up the borders
        board.borders = [ pyg.Rect(0, 0, measures.window[0], measures.top_height),
    pyg.Rect(0, measures.window[1] - measures.top_height, measures.window[0], measures.top_height),
    pyg.Rect(0, 0, measures.side_width, measures.window[1]),
    pyg.Rect(measures.window[0] - measures.side_width, 0, measures.side_width, measures.window[1]) ]

        #Reads from the file. If it doesn't find a board.json, it simply adds a new row.
        board.read_from_file()
        #Add the necessary number of balls
        for i in range(0, max(board.ball_count, 1)):
                    board.balls.add(ball.ball())
        board.update_text(True) #updates the text otherwise the ball_count text is wonky

        #Set the position of speed_button
        board.speed_button.left = measures.window[0] - board.speed_button.regular.get_rect().width - 5
        board.speed_button.top  = (board.borders[0].height - board.speed_button.regular.get_rect().height) / 2

    def add_row():
        row = []

        #3/4 chance of being a box, 1/4 chance of being 0, 0 chance of being cool
        for i in range(0, 7):
            if random.randint(1, 4) == 1:
                row.append(0)
            else:
                row.append(Box.box(board.game_level, i))

        #add the ball adder to the list at a random spot
        ball_adder_pos = random.randint(0, 6)
        del row[ball_adder_pos] 
        row.insert(ball_adder_pos, Ball_Adder.ball_adder(ball_adder_pos))

        #initiate move animation for existing rows
        game_end = False
        for i in range(len(board.board_row) - 2, -1, -1):
            for sprite in board.board_row[i].sprites():
                sprite.initiateMove()
                if i == 6: #Checks if there is a sprite in the last row 
                    game_end = True
                    break
                #Move the sprite to the next board_row
                sprite.add(board.board_row[i+1])
                sprite.remove(board.board_row[i])
            if game_end:
                break

        board.array_moving = True #Set the flag to be true as the items are moving down

        #Add the new row to the first row
        for member in row:
            if member != 0:
                board.board_row[0].add(member) 

        #check if the game has ended
        if game_end:
            for row in board.board_row:
                row.empty()
            board.game_level = 1
            board.add_row()
            for ball_ in board.balls:
                ball_.kill()
            board.ball_count = 1
            board.update_text(False)
            board.balls.add(ball.ball())

    def loop(step):
        #Set it to be false
        board.array_moving = False

        sorted_balls = sorted(board.balls.sprites(), key = lambda x: x.center[1]) 
        #sort to avoid branch prediction failure (I'm not sure this has a huge impact on performance one way or another)

        group_collision = board.collision
        for i in range(0, len(board.board_row)):
            board.board_row[i].update(step) #update each box and ball adder

            if board.board_row[i] and board.board_row[i].sprites()[0].moving: #Check if the row has any items and if the first sprite is moving
                board.array_moving = True

            if i != 7: #If i == 7 then there are boxes in the last row, at which point the game is already over.
                pyg.sprite.groupcollide(board.ball_row[i], board.board_row[i], False, False, group_collision)

        balls_grounded = True #Flag that tells whether or not the balls are on the ground

        #reassign the ball to a new row 
        for ball_ in sorted_balls:
            ball_.update(step)
            if ball_.moving == True:
                balls_grounded = False
            for i in range(0, len(board.ball_row)):
                lower = measures.ys[i]   - ball.ball.speed - measures.radius - measures.step
                upper = measures.ys[i+1] + ball.ball.speed + measures.radius + measures.step
                if lower <= ball_.center.y <= upper: #adds range to make sure that all collisions can be caught in time
                    board.ball_row[i].add(ball_)
                else:
                    board.ball_row[i].remove(ball_)

        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()

        #Displays the path of the ball before the user launches them
        if balls_grounded:
            board.display_ball_path();


        #If they are on the ground and the first flag has been set, then all balls have hit the ground just after being launched
        if  balls_grounded and ball.ball.first:
            board.speed_button.clear_state()
            ball.ball.prepare_launch() #resets first
            board.game_level += 1 
            board.ball_count = len(board.balls) #reset ball_count
            board.add_row() #add another row

        #if thread is true, the function returns true and the game loop starts a new thread using initiaite_launch which launches 
        #the balls at a set interval
        thread = False
        if pyg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and not board.array_moving and balls_grounded:
                ball.ball.prepare_launch()
                for ball_ in board.balls.sprites():
                    ball_.launching = True
                thread = True

        #display the borders
        for border in board.borders:
            pyg.draw.rect(display_surface, board.border_color, border)

        #update each piece of text
        board.update_text(balls_grounded)

        #check if speed_button has been pressed
        if not balls_grounded and board.speed_button.update():
            ball.ball.speed = 20

        if thread:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def collision(ball_, item):
        """Just handles the collisions"""
        if type(item) == Box.box:
            #convenience
            left = item.rect.left
            right = left + item.rect.width
            top = item.rect.top
            bottom = top + item.rect.height
            center = ball_.center

            #move foward 1 iteration (done so that the collisions are better)
            center -= ball.ball.speed*ball_.vector

            #rule out impossible collisions
            if center.x + measures.radius <= left or center.x - measures.radius >= right or center.y + measures.radius <= top or center.y - measures.radius >= bottom:
                center += ball.ball.speed*ball_.vector #move back one iteration
                return None # exit the function

            #find the closest point
            closest = pointOfIntersect(item.rect.center, (item.rect.width, item.rect.height), center)
            difference = center - closest

            #move back 1 iteration
            center += ball.ball.speed*ball_.vector

            #handle the collsion
            if difference.x**2 + difference.y**2 <= measures.radius**2:
                item.handle_collision()
                #find the closest point again because otherwise weird stuff happe
                closest = pointOfIntersect(item.rect.center, (item.rect.width, item.rect.height), center)

                #top/bottom
                if top - 1 <= closest.y <= top + 1 or bottom - 1 <= closest.y <= bottom + 1:
                    ball_.vector.y *= -1
                #left/right
                elif left - 1 <= closest.x <= left + 1 or right - 1 <= closest.x <= right + 1:
                    ball_.vector.x *= -1
        elif type(item) == Ball_Adder.ball_adder:
            if math.hypot(ball_.center.x - item.rect.center[0], ball_.center.y - item.rect.center[1]) < measures.radius + Ball_Adder.ball_adder.outer_radius:
                board.balls.add(ball.ball(item.rect.center[0]))
                item.handle_collision()

    def update_text(balls_grounded):
        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()
        #game level
        board.game_level_text = board.game_level_font.render(str(board.game_level), True, (255, 255, 255))

        board.game_level_rect = board.game_level_text.get_rect()
        board.game_level_rect.center = board.borders[0].center 
        display_surface.blit(board.game_level_text, board.game_level_rect)

        #ball count
        if board.ball_count != 0:
            board.gbc_text = board.gbc_font.render("x{}".format(str(board.ball_count)), True, (255,255,255))
            board.gbc_rect = board.gbc_text.get_rect()
            board.gbc_rect.center = (ball.ball.terminus.x, ball.ball.terminus.y - 3*measures.radius)
            display_surface.blit(board.gbc_text, board.gbc_rect)

        #mouse angle
        if balls_grounded:
            board.mouse_angle = math.acos(board.balls.sprites()[0].vector.x)
            board.ma_text = board.game_level_font.render(str(round(180 - (board.mouse_angle * 180)/math.pi, 1)) + "°", True, (255, 255, 255))

            board.ma_rect = board.ma_text.get_rect()
            board.ma_rect.center = board.borders[1].center
            display_surface.blit(board.ma_text, board.ma_rect)

    def initiate_launch(event):
        """Launches balls at timed intervals"""
        vector = tuple(board.balls.sprites()[0].vector) #save the vector so that the user can't change the trajectory mid-launch
        for ball_ in board.balls.sprites():
            event.wait(timeout=0.08)
            ball_.center = pyg.math.Vector2(ball.ball.terminus.x, ball.ball.terminus.y)
            ball_.launch()
            ball_.vector = pyg.math.Vector2(vector)
            board.ball_count -= 1
            event.clear()

    def display_ball_path():
        """Displays the path of the balls"""
        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()

        spacing = 40
        start = pyg.math.Vector2(ball.ball.terminus.x, ball.ball.terminus.y)
        end = pyg.math.Vector2(pyg.mouse.get_pos())
        length = (start - end).length()
        unit_vector = pyg.math.Vector2(start - end)
        unit_vector.normalize_ip()
        initial_ball = start - spacing*unit_vector

        while (initial_ball - start).length() <= length:
            gfxdraw.aacircle(display_surface, int(initial_ball.x), int(initial_ball.y), measures.radius, (255,255,255))
            gfxdraw.filled_circle(display_surface, int(initial_ball.x), int(initial_ball.y), measures.radius, (255,255,255))
            initial_ball -= spacing*unit_vector

    def read_from_file():
        """Read from the saved json file or, if it does not exist, then just add a row"""
        if os.path.isfile("Saves/board.json") and os.path.getsize("Saves/board.json") != 0:
            with open("Saves/board.json", 'r') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                board.game_level = data["game level"]
                board.ball_count = data["ball count"]
                ball.ball.terminus.x   = data  ["terminus"]
                ball.ball.new_terminus_x = ball.ball.terminus.x
                board.balls.empty()
                for i in range(0, len(board.board_row)):
                    for member in data[str(i)]:
                        x = measures.xs.index(member[0])
                        if member[1] != 0:
                            board.board_row[i].add(Box.box(board.game_level, x, i-1, member[1]))
                        else:
                            board.board_row[i].add(Ball_Adder.ball_adder(x, i-1))
                f.close()
        else:
            board.add_row()


    def write_to_file():
        """Write to the json file"""
        with open("Saves/board.json", 'w') as f:
            data = {"game level": board.game_level, "ball count" : len(board.balls), "terminus": ball.ball.terminus.x}

            balls_grounded = False
            while board.array_moving or not balls_grounded:
                board.loop(0.5)
                balls_grounded = True
                for ball_ in board.balls.sprites():
                    if ball_.moving == True:
                        balls_grounded = False

                pyg.display.flip()

            for i in range(0, len(board.board_row)):
                subdata = []
                for sprite in board.board_row[i]:
                    if type(sprite) == Box.box:
                        subdata.append((sprite.rect.left, sprite.number))
                    else:
                        subdata.append((sprite.rect.left, 0))
                data[i] = subdata

            json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
            f.close()
```

---

**button.py**

```
import pygame as pyg

class button_image:
    def __init__(self, left, top, image_path, pressed_image_path, color_key):
        self.regular = pyg.image.load(image_path)
        self.pressed = pyg.image.load(pressed_image_path)
        #self.regular.convert_alpha()
        #self.presssed.convert_alpha()
        self.regular.set_colorkey(color_key)
        self.pressed.set_colorkey(color_key)

        self.left = left
        self.top = left
        self.state = False

    def check_hover(self):
        rectangle = self.regular.get_rect()
        rectangle.left = self.left
        rectangle.top = self.top

        if rectangle.collidepoint(pyg.mouse.get_pos()):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def check_click(self):
        if self.check_hover() and pyg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            self.state = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def draw(self):
        display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()
        if self.state:
            display_surface.blit(self.pressed, (self.left, self.top))  
        else:
            display_surface.blit(self.regular, (self.left, self.top))

    def update(self):
        self.draw()
        return self.check_click()

    def clear_state(self):
        self.state = False
```

---

And, finally, the main file: **Ballz.py**

```
import pygame as pyg
import Board
import threading
import measures

#main function
def main():
    pyg.init()

    #initialize and set the icon
    pyg.display.set_mode(measures.window)
    pyg.display.set_icon(pyg.image.load("Images/Icon.png"))
    pyg.display.set_caption("Ballz")

    display_surface = pyg.display.get_surface()

    #create game clock for keeping the framerate constant
    game_clock = pyg.time.Clock()

    Board.board.init()

    running = True
    while running:
        game_clock.tick(60) #keeps framerate at a maximum of 60

        #Handle events
        for event in pyg.event.get():
            if event.type == pyg.QUIT:
                running = False
                break

        #Draw
        try: #In place because sometimes, when I exit the program during debug, this particular section triggers an error.
            display_surface.fill((33, 33, 33))
        except:
            break

        #print("FPS: ",  int(game_clock.get_fps()))

        thread = False
        event = threading.Event()
        for i in range(0,2): #Call it twice so collisions have a finer granularity
            if Board.board.loop(0.5):
                thread = True #makes sure that it is not called twice
        if thread:    
            ball_launch = threading.Thread(target=Board.board.initiate_launch, args=(event,))
            ball_launch.start()

        event.set()

        pyg.display.flip()

    Board.board.write_to_file() #Write to the file once the game is over 

    pyg.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

While it is not necessary to have the exact same font and images, here are the ones I used

- Roboto and Roboto light can be found [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), and must be saved in the `Fonts/` directory of the project file
- The lightning images are right here: [image] [image] (These are to be saved in `Images/`)
- Finally, the icon image: [image]

---

Also, here is a GIF of what the program looks like. As you can see, the game is somewhat laggy starting around game level 50:
[image]

Comment: This is nothing like Ballz, where's the bajillion of adverts?! In all seriousness, this is so cool nice job! I hope this gets answered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more of a Java guy, but I'll add my 2 cents on the collision detection, because you said it was not always working properly; I think you might solve this by creating a 'vecor' object, or ray. The idea is simple; instead of checking the static shapes, check if the vector intersects a block; and take the first intersection.

In 1D:

```
 t   ---O--------|BLOCK|-----------------
 t+1 ------------|BLOCK|-O---------------
```

If the ball is moving quickly it will miss the shape of the block.

Now transform the ball to a 'ray'. If you follow the ray, you'll see it hits the left of the block.

```
 t   ---O--------|BLOCK|-----------------
 ray ---O>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>--------------
```

You now know it will collide with the left of the block and can calculate the bounce:

```
 t   ---O--------|BLOCK|-----------------
 ray ---O>>>>>>>>------------------------
       <<<<<<<<<<
 t+1 --O---------|BLOCK|-----------------
```

So the ball should be at the new position.

Comment: What I do currently is divide the board into rows, and update the row of every ball each loop and check for circle-rectangle collisions normally. Do you think this would be a performance improvement, or end up slowing the game down further? From what I understand, the collisions of 3 different lines must be calculated (otherwise some collisions would be missed). Additionally, should I have to check the lines against every single other box, or should I keep what I have now where ball-box collision is only checked within rows?

Comment: @Erdogan yes it will take more processing power if you need to calculate more boxes. However, if you partition your space (for example using quadtrees) you can quick eliminate a whole lot of boxes to check

Comment: I looked at the Wikipedia page for quadtrees and I (kind of) understand them, but I'm not really sure how a quadtree would be implemented with collision detection. Could you point me to an example or explain roughly how one would work?

Comment: @Erdogan [Here's](http://www.fundza.com/algorithmic/quadtree/index.html) one.